# Release an Eclipse project

Tags: java, swing

I'm ready to send out betas of my **Eclipse** project to my friends. I have already tried to make an executable jar, which worked on my computer. But when sent to my friends (who use Ubuntu and Mac OSX), they couldn't execute the jar. How can I send out a full copy of my current project so that it works on all OSs?

Comment: Are you sure it's swing and not swt? How exactly did you export it? WHat's the classpath of your project?

Comment: I'm sure it's Swing. I exported it by File -> Export -> Runnable JAR file -> (selected where i wanted it to go). When i double click it, it works.

Comment: And what, precisely, happens to your friends?

Comment: It wouldn't execute for them. My ubuntu friend even used chmod +x, and that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to launch the project off a web server.  This will work for any OS with Java (1.4.2+) installed, and some earlier JREs as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps not what you want, but it comes from a voice of experience.

Do not use eclipse as a build tool to make things you release.

Learn ant or maven (or buildr or something). Use eclipse as your IDE, but when you want something to send to someone somewhere else, use a command-line build tool.

Comment: the web is full of tutorials on ant and maven: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have dependencies in your project that are installed on your machine and not on theirs?

Comment: It's just made with Swing. So if they have Java installed, they probably can run this.